# CMS theme. "404 not found" on any link click

Tags: content-management-system, http-status-code-404, actionlink

Well, this is the code included in Header.html on my site. Whenever I click on Topics, Home, or any link that leads to (www.mywebsite/THElink) I get a 404 page not found. However, on the demo of the CMS theme, those links give information taken from MySQL Db which also I have configured right.

```
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li {if isset($is_home) AND $is_home eq 1}class="active"  {/if}><a href="./">Home</a></li>
                <li {if isset($is_topics) AND $is_topics eq 1}class="active"{/if}><a href="./topics">Topics</a></li>
                <li {if isset($is_authors) AND $is_authors eq 1}class="active"{/if}><a href="./authors">Authors</a></li>

            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right search-nav">
                <li class="search-form">
                    <form method="GET" action="./search/">
                        <div class="input-group">
                          <input type="text" name="q" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Quotes" {if isset($is_search) AND $is_search eq 1}value="{$q}"{/if} />
                          <span class="input-group-addon"><button type="submit" class="btn-link"><span class="fa fa-search"></span></button></span>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's just an issue of .htaccess file. This particular file has huge impact on the whole site.